# How to authenticate the MYSQL server when username or password has Non ASCII characters?

Tags: mysql

I cannot connect to MYSQL server if username/password contains some non-ascii characters. I researched for this issue and found some important article.

> It is possible to connect to the server regardless of character set
>   settings if the user name and password contain only ASCII characters.
>   To connect when the user name or password contain non-ASCII
>   characters, the client should call the mysql_options() C API function
>   with the MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME option and appropriate character set
>   name as arguments. This causes authentication to take place using the
>   specified character set. Otherwise, authentication will fail unless
>   the server default character set is the same as the encoding in the
>   authentication defaults.

How to implement C API function like mysql_options() in order to authenticate the users having non-ascii characters in their username?

Regards,

Comment: What languag are you developing in?

Comment: I am using Python.